# Recommended reserve hard disk space is not present on the Hyper-V host

Tags: hyper-v

Running the [TFS 2010 Best Practices Analyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee248630.aspx) gives the following warning:

> Recommended reserve hard disk space is not present on the Hyper-V host

The [help page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966334.aspx) suggests to resolve these warnings, follow the instructions in [Configuring Lab Management for the First Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd380687%28VS.100%29.aspx).

The only thing I can see on that page is a reference to setting a memory reserve of 1024 - nothing about disk space.

So what is the correct value to set the to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is hard-coded in Get-HostDetails.ps1 (Located by default in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer\scripts\Get-HostDetails.ps1")

This script raises the warning if the reserve disk space is less than 100 GB

```
# reserve hdd should be 100 GB
if([double]$h.DiskSpaceReserveMB -lt 100*1024)
{
    $ax.InSufficientReserveHDD = $true
}
```